# API Management Encryptipon and Decryption

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am planning to decrypt header value using the deployed certificate of Azure API management. But not able to implement it in policies.

But I end up getting exception:

**Usage of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions' is not supported within expressions**

Can some one please tell how to use decrypt and encrypt?

Answer (score 0):

Does not seem to be possible at the moment to use RSACertificateExtensions class. But since it's only container for extension methods, perhaps you could inline method you're interested in into a policy itself? What code are you trying to write?